# Issue with basic Python loop

Tags: python

Issue with basic Python Loop. 
I am trying to extract stock tickers from a PDF ... the PDF reads fine and converts to a string. Then once the code hits the for loop, the program runs for 5+ minutes (PyCharms).

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('JULY1919.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

i = 0
x = ''
while i < pdfReader.numPages:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    i += 1
    x += pageObj.extractText()

y = 0
tickers = ['']
while y < len(x):
    ticker = x[y:y + 1]
    if ticker.isupper():
        print(ticker)
        tickers[y] = ticker

print(tickers)
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell which loop it is stuck in?

Comment: If neither `x` nor `y` change inside the `while y < len(x):` loop, there's no reason to expect it to ever finish looping. If you want to iterate over each element of `x`, use `for`, not `while`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I see two issues with what you've posted: First, there's no `for` loop in your code. Second, in your second `while` loop, you never increment `y`, so it never terminates your loop

Answer (score 0):

```
while y < len(x):
    ticker = x[y:y + 1]
    if ticker.isupper():
        print(ticker)
        tickers[y] = ticker
```

You never change the value of `y` in the loop.  How do you expect to exit the loop?  Did you miss a `y += 1`, perhaps?

Also, note that `x[y:y + 1]` is the same as simply `x[y]`; what did you intend here?  If you truly want only the single letter, this is much easier as

```
for y, ticker in enumerate(x):
    if ticker.isupper():
        print(ticker)
        tickers[y] = ticker
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the second while loop you didn't change the value of **y** in it.

For easily handling this loop go for **for loop**.

```
for y, ticker in enumerate(x):
    if ticker.isupper():
        print(ticker)
        tickers[y] = ticker
```